# Is there any possibility to change a frozen title of the app?

Tags: facebook, title

I created an app with the codename as its name and after initial testing while app was in sandbox, I changed its name to a right one and it udpated on most actions seen on facebook pages.

Now, after getting out of sandbox and app being visited by many users, I get reports that in some places the first, old name appears. In debugger I see the old name appear in og:title and the notice about the title being frozen and no possibility to update it from metatags...

Is there any way to change the title to the current name of app? In most places it shows the new name, but there are some places (like "recent played games") where the old name is seen and I don't think such change would be in any way harmful for Facebook users.

Comment: Have you tried running the app's URLs through the [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) tool to clear the cache?

Comment: Yes, that's where I saw the notice saying that the title is frozen and cannot be changed.